# Kotlin - convert string to generic type

Tags: kotlin, jpa

Here's my function

```
fun <T, U> fetchChildEntity(childEntityName: String?): Specification<T> {
    return Specification { root: Root<T>, query: CriteriaQuery<*>, builder: 
        CriteriaBuilder -> 
    root.fetch<T, U>(childEntityName, JoinType.LEFT)
    null
   }
}
```

I'm attempting to call it like this, using a string "child":

```
val childClass: Class<*>? = Class.forName(child)::class.java
val fetchChild: Specification<childClass> = fetchChildEntity<parent::class.java, childClass>(field.name)
```

But I'm getting an unresolved reference error for "childClass". I tried using this :

```
fun getType(string: String): Class<*>? {
        return when (string) {
            Employee::javaClass.toString() -> Employee::class.java
            else -> null
        }
    }
```

but I see the same error. So, I have a string that corresponds to an entity class, and I need to convert that to a "Type".

Comment: You can't pass a variable to a generic type. You can only directly pass a type. A `Class<*>` is not a type. You cannot pass a runtime-determined type to a generic function. This doesn't even make sense, because generics are only useful at compile time and are erased at runtime. For example, your function returns `Specification<T>` but if you don't know know what `T` is at compile time, it might as well be `Specification<*>`.

Comment: Thanks - that helps a lot. Do you have any ideas on how I could accomplish this "dynamic" spec creation? Can you point me to any resources that might help? Again, thanks much.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JPA, so I don't really know what you're trying to do, sorry.